# Multiple Ordeals of Nylea on one creature

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have 2 counters on a creature, with 3 [Ordeal of Nylea](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOrdeal%20of%20Nylea%5d) attached, and then attack, what in all (preferably step by step) happens next?

Comment: There are quite a few rules that are relevant to the question. What part of the outcome of this situation are you unsure about?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I was worried about the same thing as eggo, Someone had told me that you sacrifice all 3 after the 1st counter is added, not one at a time after each counter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic answer is that the creature gets 3 more counters (for a total of 5), you sacrifice all 3 Ordeals, and you search your library for 6 basic lands and put them onto the battlefield tapped.

Step by step, here's what happens:

1. You attack with the creature.
2. Abilities that trigger when you attack are put on the stack. In this case, that is the first ability of each of the 3 Ordeals attached to the creature.
3. The first ability of the first Ordeal resolves. You put a counter on the creature. It has 3 or more counters, so you sacrifice the Ordeal. The Ordeal's second ability triggers, and is put on the stack.
4. Each player gains priority, and has an opportunity to respond.
5. The second ability of the first Ordeal resolves. You search your library for 2 basic lands, and put them on the battlefield tapped.
6. Each player gains priority, and has an opportunity to respond.
7. Steps 3-6 repeat for each of the second and the third Ordeal. In each of those iterations, you put another counter on the creature, sacrifice that Ordeal, and search for 2 more lands.

Comment: the creature gets three *more* counters, right?  Given that it started with two has no relevance to the fact that the first half of the triggered ability of Ordeal will add a counter before the second half of the ability causes it to be sacrificed.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. I tried to make that clear in the step-by-step explanation by saying that you add a counter, then check for having 3 or more in step 3.